# R : rpart with multiple values prediction

Tags: r, prediction, rpart

I am comparing predictions between different methods 
the 1st method is linear regression (lm) and the 2nd is rpart

the lm is ok, i send 2 variables and i get a 2 variables.

but with rpart, i dont get the same , i just get 1 variable.

why not getting 2 results 1 for y1 and the other for y2

this is my code

```
######################################
##  S E T U P
######################################

x1 <- c(11,  21,  20,  36,  27,  15,  7,   19,  40,  5 )
x2 <- c(142, 175, 175, 180, 181, 160, 110, 170, 177, 92)
x3 <- c(44,  78,  79,  82,  92,  56,  31,  66,  91,  29)
y1 <- c(36,  41,  42,  44,  45,  40,  34,  41,  45,  32)
y2 <- c(7,   13,  13,  17,  19,  11,  6,   12,  19,  4)

TData <- data.frame(x1=x1[1:7], x2=x2[1:7], x3=x3[1:7], y1=y1[1:7], y2=y2[1:7])
PData <- data.frame(x1=x1[8:10], x2=x2[8:10], x3=x3[8:10], y1=y1[8:10], y2=y2[8:10])

######################################
## LINEAR REGRESSION
######################################

lm_Result <- lm(cbind(y1,y2)~., TData)

lm_pred <- predict(lm_Result, PData)

lr_pred[,"y1"]
lr_pred[,"y2"]


######################################
## RPART
######################################

library(rpart)

rpart_Result <- rpart(cbind(y1,y2)~., TData)

rpart_pred <- predict(rpart_Result, PData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why not getting 2 results 1 for y1 and the other for y2

This is because **the `predict` method returns different classes, depending on the argument which you have passed.**

If you try:

```
?Predict
```

Then it says:

> Predict is a generic function for predictions from the results of various model fitting functions. The function invokes particular
>   methods which depend on the class of the first argument.

and its value is:

> The form of the value returned by predict depends on the class of its argument.

So, the response of `lm` method is an object of class `lm`, meanwhile the return value of `rpart` is An object of class `rpart`

Therefore, the predict method provides you different answers.

---

**What can you do to get the same result?**

your lm method made a model to estimate the values of `y1`, and `y2`. So, you should run the rpart in a way that it also obtains the values of `y1`, and `y2`.

To do this in your `rpart` method define `method="class"`, but it fails. Because it cannot classify 2 features. Therefore, **the biggest problem comes from your formula**, where you have `cbind(y1,y2)~.`

Reading [Rpart document](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-13/topics/rpart) helps you a lot.